# How to remove special characters from the end of an Access text field?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a field in MS Access that contains thousands of records.  The records contain names.  Many of those names are followed by a special character. For instance `John Smith*` or `Joe Smith#`

I want to leave the names as they are but I want to get rid of those special characters at the end of each name. I tried find and replace but maybe I wasn't using the right syntax.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Show us your attempt! Help us reproduce your error!

Comment: `UPDATE NameTable SET NameColumn = Left(NameColumn, Len(NameColumn) - 1) WHERE NameColumn NOT LIKE "*[a-z]"` perhaps?

Comment: Review https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-Find-and-Replace-dialog-box-to-change-data-2EEE8D02-5A40-4328-BA56-EC0406865680#bm6. Leave the Replace box blank.

Comment: In know how to use the query wizard but how would you just enter the query in the line format that Gord shows in his response?

Comment: On the "Design" tab, choose View > SQL View : [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVWnl.png)

Comment: It worked thanks Gord! Is there something I should do when the question has been resolved?

Comment: Yes, you should accept Gord's answer if it worked. See [how accepting works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (you even get 2 rep for it yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an UPDATE query like so:

```sql
UPDATE NameTable SET NameColumn = Left(NameColumn, Len(NameColumn) - 1) 
WHERE NameColumn NOT LIKE "*[a-z]"
```

In the Query Builder it would look like this:

[image]